# Connection was not closed. Connection's current State was open

Tags: c#

I'm currently finishing my payroll system with ms access database used to connect with my program. CRUD is one of our main requirements to finish  this project but ADD button said that my connection was not closed. Connection's current State was open.

```
private void btnAddDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbCommand command3 = new OleDbCommand();
        command1.Connection = Connection;
        command2.Connection = Connection;
        command3.Connection = Connection;            
        command1.CommandText = "Select* from employeeinfo where Employee ID = '" + txtEID.Text + "'";
        OleDbDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader();
        command2.CommandText = "Select* from employeeinfo where Email Address = '" + txtEA.Text + "'";
        OleDbDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
        command3.CommandText = "Select* from employeeinfo where Contact Number = '" + txtCN.Text + "'";
        OleDbDataReader reader3 = command3.ExecuteReader();

        string conn1, conn2, conn3;
        while (reader1.Read())
        {
            con1.Text = reader1["Employee ID"].ToString();
        }
        while (reader2.Read())
        {
            con2.Text = reader2["Email Address"].ToString();
        }
        while (reader3.Read())
        {
            con3.Text = reader3["Contact Number"].ToString();
        }

        conn1 = con1.Text;
        if (conn1 != con1.Text)
        {
            conn2 = con2.Text;
            if (conn2 != con2.Text)
            {
                conn3 = con3.Text;
                if (conn3 != con3.Text)
                {

                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                    command.Connection = Connection;
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO employeeinfo ([Employee ID], [Employee Name], [Department], [First Name], [Middle Name, [Surname], [Address], [Contact Number], [Email Address], [Salary]) values(@empid, @empname, @dep, @fname, @mname, @sname, @address, @connum, @emadd, @sal)";

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", txtEID.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empname", txtEN.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dep", txtDep.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFN.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", txtMN.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", txtSN.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAdd.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@connum", txtCN.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emadd", txtEA.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sal", textBox2.Text);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Employee Information Created");
                }
                else if (conn3 == txtCN.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Contact Number Already exist");
                    con3.Text = "";
                }
            }
            else if (conn2 == txtEA.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Email Address Already exist");
                con2.Text = "";
            }
        }
        else if (conn1 == txtEID.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Email ID Already exist");
            con1.Text = "";
        }
        Connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh and fyi we're not here to do your schoolwork.

Comment: Your command will never be executed.  You are setting `conn1 = con1.Text`, then checking `if (conn1 != con1.Text)` which will never be true.

Comment: It actually don't post any data to my datagridview

Comment: Nobody is talking about a datagridview... Voting to close

Comment: I'm here needing some help. don't be so rude.

Comment: Also, please don't unnecessarily bold your text. Boldness is for emphasis. If you bold entire paragraphs it makes others not want to read it.

Comment: I did try to help you, did you read my comment?

Comment: Thanks alot Brandon. :)